# In $\Delta ABC$, if C=90, then prove that $1+\sin A- \sin B=\frac{r_1}{R}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

*All symbols have their usual meanings. If any confusion occurs, please let me know*

Then,
$$1+2\sin{\frac{A-B}{2}} \cos{ \frac{A+B}{2}}$$
$\cos \frac{A+B}{2}=\sin\frac C2$

So
$$1+2\sin\frac{A-B}{2}$$
I don’t know how to proceed. Thanks

**R is the radius of the circumcircle around the triangle**

**$r_1$ is the radius of the ex circle on side ‘a’, which is opposite to angle A**

Comment: What are $R$ and $r_1$?

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: I would try to express $R$ and $r_1$ in terms of the sides $a,b,c$ and then note that your expression is really $$1 + \sin A - \sin B = 1 + \frac{a}{c} - \frac{b}{c}$$

Comment: @gt6989b I am not getting anywhere with that. Got stuck at $\frac{2s-2b}{c}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From the diagram, we have $BC = x +r_1$ and  AP = AQ, which lead to

$$a = x + r_1, \>\>\>\>\>x+c=r_1+b$$

Eliminate $x$ to get

$$r_1 = \frac{c+a-b}2$$

Thus, with $R=\frac c2$ and $\sin C = 1$,

$$\frac{r_1}R =\frac{c+a-b}c= 1+ \frac{\sin A - \sin B}{\sin C} = 1+ \sin A - \sin B$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\angle C = 90^\circ$, then $r_1=p-b$. The identity becomes:

$$\frac{c+a-b}{c} = \frac{p-b}{c/2},$$

which is obvious.

[image]

Comment: If you mean p to be the semi perimeter, then I already did that (check the comments on my question). I can't solve ahead of this thouh

Comment: @Aditya see the updated picture, note that $AF=AH=p$ for general triangle, while the fact that $\angle C=90^\circ$ implies that $EFCG$ is a square.

Answer (score 0):

Extend AC  and AB to touch the ex circle on a at D and E respectively. the two tangents from A on ex circle are equal and we have:

$AB+BE=AC+CD$

$AB+BE+CD=AC+2CD$

But:

$CD=r_1$

$CD+BE=BC=a$

⇒ $c+a=b+2r_1$ ⇒$c+a-b=2r_1$

Dividing both sides by c/2=R we get:

$2(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{c}-\frac{b}{c})=\frac{2r_1}{R}$

⇒ $1+ Sin A - Sin B=\frac {r_1}{R}$